# Is it possible to make a event channel with a custom name WHILE logging into a subfolder with ETW in the Event Viewer?

Tags: c#, windows, etw, event-viewer, etw-eventsource

Here is my problem:

I first tried to implement folders in the Event Viewer under "Application and Services", but the `System.Diagnostics.EventLog` Class does not seem to support this.
So then I encountered ETW, which provides the ability to create events for event tracing for Windows.
They left some samples and documentation in a NuGet-Package, and I'm able to set my own hierarchy up until the actual Event Channel now, but here is the problem:
The [Event Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventchannel?view=net-5.0) Names are predefined, which means that I can't choose the name manually.
That's what they wrote to it, which confuses me even more:

```
//     EventChannel. Custom values must be in the range from 16 through 255. Currently
//     only predefined values allowed.
```

Now are the names customizable or not, is there maybe a completely different way of doing all of this?
I've read through tons of posts and none of them were able to create "folders" within the Event Viewer with the `System.Diagnostics.EventLog` class, now with ETW it is possible however it leaves this problem behind.

Thanks in advance!